# Node.js Read/Parse ini file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ini

I have tried numerous npms such and ini, node-ini, config-ini-parser, iniparser, ini-parser-encoder and more. I just want to read my ini files sections that look like this.

```
[pos]
x=785
y=433
[ChatMessages]
ChatMessage1=test
ChatMessage2=sadsad
ChatMessage3=dsasda
ChatMessage4=sadd
ChatMessage5=asd
ChatMessage6=312
ChatMessage7=213
ChatMessage8=231
ChatMessage9=dsa
ChatMessage10=hfghfg
[TwitchName]
Name=Test
[ClientIDAuth]
ClientID=dsa
Auth=hfghfg
```

In node.js I want to read a variable in the section and set it as a variable in node.js, such as the name in [TwitchName].
When I tried the npms they either result in undefined or some weird jumble of letters and numbers looking like this.

```
 '��[\u0000p\u0000o\u0000s\u0000]\u0000': true,
  '\u0000': true,
  '\u0000x\u0000': '\u00007\u00008\u00005\u0000',
  '\u0000y\u0000': '\u00004\u00003\u00003\u0000',
  '\u0000[\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u0000s\u0000]\u0000': true,
  '\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u00001\u0000': '\u0000t\u0000e\u0000s\u0000t\u0000',
  '\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u00002\u0000': '\u0000s\u0000a\u0000d\u0000s\u0000a\u0000d\u0000',
  '\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u00003\u0000': '\u0000d\u0000s\u0000a\u0000s\u0000d\u0000a\u0000',
  '\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u00004\u0000': '\u0000s\u0000a\u0000d\u0000d\u0000',
  '\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u00005\u0000': '\u0000a\u0000s\u0000d\u0000',
  '\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u00006\u0000': '\u00003\u00001\u00002\u0000',
  '\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u00007\u0000': '\u00002\u00001\u00003\u0000',
  '\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u00008\u0000': '\u00002\u00003\u00001\u0000',
  '\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u00009\u0000': '\u0000d\u0000s\u0000a\u0000',
  '\u0000C\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000M\u0000e\u0000s\u0000s\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u00001\u00000\u0000': '\u0000h\u0000f\u0000g\u0000h\u0000f\u0000g\u0000'
```

This is how my current code looks like.

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , ini = require('ini')

var config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.ini', 'utf-8'));

console.log(config);
```

Comment: seems you must be reading it with the wrong encoding, please show your code, node-ini works like a charm https://runkit.com/lcherone/603a8581b3dd31001a31ad9b

Comment: Edited my post with my code, thats weird how it works when its in the file but when its external it turns up weird

Comment: Your file is filled with NULs. Try editing it from something like a Bash shell with a tool like Vim or Nano and seeing if that fixes it.

Comment: Wow, thank you I found out it was how AHK makes the file... I was trying to figure out why it works on a newly created file vs the one that AHK made.